# Change stock availability on attribute drop down change

Tags: magento-1.9

On my configurable product page, under the title is a stock availability label that simply says 'in stock'.

I have a dropdown with various color attributes.

I want to make it so when I change the color in the dropdown, the stock availability label is updated to say "We have x products left"

I just need to know where the stock availability label is derived from after the attribute dropdown is changed.

Comment: I think this question here has the answer you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482790/get-stock-of-selected-simple-in-magento